# BigQuery WHERE statement filter out pairs of values

Tags: google-bigquery, conditional-statements, where-clause

I have a table with multiple rows and the following fields:

| Visitor | Host | Event | Time |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |

The table lists visitors to a building. Visitor is the name of a visitor, Host is the company they are visiting, and Event is either 'IN' or 'OUT' indicating that the visitor has entered or exited the building at Time

| Visitor | Host | Event | Time |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Alan | GraphicsMan | IN | 12:34 |
| Alan | GraphicsMan | OUT | 13:44 |
| Barry | CodeMan | IN | 14:31 |
| Carla | CodeMan | IN | 15:10 |
| Danielle | SecureMan | IN | 15:13 |
| Carla | CodeMan | OUT | 15:31 |
| Carla | SecureMan | IN | 15:35 |

I want my query to return all visitors who are currently visiting and who they are visiting. In other words, I want all visitor-host pairs that have an 'IN' event but do not have an 'OUT' event. For the example table above, the query should return:

| Visitor | Host | Event | Time |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Barry | CodeMan | IN | 14:31 |
| Danielle | SecureMan | IN | 15:13 |
| Carla | SecureMan | IN | 15:35 |

The closest I've gotten is the following:

```
with entrances as (SELECT visitor FROM table where event = 'IN'), 
exits as (SELECT visitor FROM table WHERE event = 'OUT'),
SELECT * from table
WHERE visitor IN entrances AND visitor NOT IN exits
```

which returns

| Visitor | Host | Event | Time |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Barry | CodeMan | IN | 14:31 |
| Danielle | SecureMan | IN | 15:13 |

Carla will be excluded because she went in and out of the building before going back in to visit a different host. I'm trying to think of a way to check pairs of values (i.e. a visitor-host pair) in the where clause.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming OUT is always timestamped **after** IN, `COUNT` can be used to find cases where IN does not have a corresponding OUT.

```sql
SELECT visitor, host, time
FROM (
    SELECT
        visitor, host,
        COUNTIF(event='IN') ins, COUNTIF(event='OUT') outs,
        MAX(time) time
    FROM table
    GROUP BY visitor, host
    HAVING ins > outs)
```

It should return:

| Row | visitor | host | time |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Barry | CodeMan | 14:31:00 |
| 2 | Carla | SecureMan | 15:35:00 |
| 3 | Danielle | SecureMan | 15:13:00 |

Comment: This is a pretty smart approach. Thank you for your help!

Comment: @SyedHussaini Please close your question by accepting this answer. BR